# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified while using distinct

Tags: sql-server-2012

I Added Distinct Keyword in Below Query. But getting error like "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

```
  SELECT @cols = STUFF(( SELECT  distinct TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + t2.Description
  FROM table1 AS t2 where t2.EntityTypeId=@EntitytypeID
    ORDER BY '],[' + CONVERT(Varchar, t2.SortOrder)
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') + ']'
```

Comment: It's meaningless to have `ORDER BY something` when `something` is not in the `SELECT DISTINCT` list.

Answer (score 0):

What is unclear about the error message?

You select

```
'],[' + t2.Description
```

and you sort on

```
'],[' + CONVERT(Varchar, t2.SortOrder)
```

So your ORDER BY item is not in your SELECT.

I am guessing SQL does not know how to distinguish unique rows if duplicates cannot be located in a meaningful way (not know, or rather, refuses to do it as it would be extremely inefficient.)

If your ORDER BY can be used to locate duplicate entries, it is easy (and fast) to eliminate duplicate records. But you are ordering on a different field all together, so to find duplicates, a search of the complete list would be necessary for each record, just to determine if it has a duplicate.

As you are selection for XML, I don't think you can easily put your order by in your select clause.

So you have some other options:

- Drop the order by (is it really necessary that your xml is ordered? If so, include the SortOrder as an attribute in your xml maybe?)
- Drop the distinct (you would have to remove duplicate nodes from your xml later)
- Create a temporary table without duplicates first and select your ordered data from there.